# Prawn PDF only produce records for current user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, prawn

Ive recently implemened the Prawn PDF gem

I have the PDF reports working but when i add the code to only show records for current user. (See code Below)

```
  def initialize(requests)
    super()
    @requests = Request.where(completed_at: [false, nil]).where(house: current_user.houses).order("created_at DESC")
    request_title
    request_id
  end
```

I get the following error undefined local variable or method `current_user' prawn.

It works when the code is below, but this does not filter to the current users records.

```
class RequestPdf < Prawn::Document
  def initialize(requests)
    super()
    @requests = Request.where(completed_at: [false, nil]).order("created_at DESC")
    request_title
    request_id
  end
```

I have also tried to implement this in the requests_controller but it does not change the output of the PDF.

Thank you in advanced

Comment: app github: https://github.com/kushrajdev/landlordapp.git

Answer (score 1):

I would use the sign in helpers... You probably will need to include them directly into that Prawn subclass.

`user_signed_in?`

The helpers are really meant for your controllers. They don't play nice inside the models. You probably will need to pass the current_user from the controller to your class/model code.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. But i do not thi is relevant. As i need Prawn to filter records for the specifc user signed in.

Answer (score 0):

I would send the current_user value to the initialize method.

Wherever you are calling this, probably looks something like this, change it to also pass the current user value.

```
something = RequestPdf.new(requests, current_user)
```

and then change the initializer

```
  def initialize(requests, current_user)
    super()
    @user = current_user
    @requests = Request.where(completed_at: [false, nil]).order("created_at DESC")
    request_title
    request_id
  end
```

Comment: Hi @RickwellRice This solution looks like it would work! but i get a missing template error unfortunately. The applcation is on git https://github.com/kushrajdev/landlordapp.git, if you would like to test :)

Comment: must be a private repo.  Where is your `RequestPdf.rb` file located, is it in the `lib` directory?

Comment: I changed it too public and its in app\pdf. Thanks